# Why IFS impact subshell variable?

Tags: ksh

This KSH code working fine on AIX and RH with the standard IFS (default)

```
[ "$(uname)" = "AIX" ] && ECHO="echo" || ECHO="echo -e"
echo "AA BB CC DD" | while read a b c d; do
[ "`$ECHO $a | cut -c1-2`" = "AA" ] && echo $b
done
```

If i set a different IFS like a ; for example

```
[ "$(uname)" = "AIX" ] && ECHO="echo" || ECHO="echo -e"
IFS=";"
echo "AA;BB;CC;DD" | while read a b c d; do
[ "`$ECHO $a | cut -c1-2`" = "AA" ] && echo $b
done
```

I get an error like only on RH not Aix

```
+ echo 'AA;BB;CC;DD'
+ read a b c d
+ cut -c1-2
+ 'echo -e' AA
-ksh: line 3: echo -e: not found
+ [ '' '=' AA ]
+ read a b c d
+ echo .....
+ cut -d. -f1
```

Someone can explain me why this is happening and how we can solved it without a eval ?
Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Try this: `echo "AA;BB;CC;DD" | while IFS=';' read a b c d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `ECHO="echo -e"`, then you set `IFS=";"`, so when you expand $ECHO unquoted (where globbing and word splitting will take effect), you get `echo -e` as a single word (because you are word splitting using semicolon not whitespace), and of course there's no such command.

You'll want to refer to [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). The answer is to use an array:

```
[ "$(uname)" = "AIX" ] && ECHO=(echo) || ECHO=(echo -e)
```

And then, use it like

```
"${ECHO[@]}" "$a" | cut -c1-2
```

You'll also need to use quotes more. Refer to [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

(todo: discuss not using "echo -e"...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and sense answer :-)

Comment: After few test this doesn't work as well. I have some others troubles when i used an array like ECHO=(echo -e) or typeset -a ECHO=(echo -e). i replaced "echo -e" with print command. so my first syntax running well ECHO="print".

Comment: All of that, plus using `print` instead of `echo`, plus using `$(…)` style of command substitution because you **cannot** use double quotes both outside and inside of the deprecated accent-gravis-style command substitutions.